# Why won't an HTML link work inside a transparent bordered div?

Tags: css, z-index

I originally setup a single `<div>`, `z-index`ed above other content. I couldn't click through because even though it was transparent, it wasn't clickable.

I tried to split the pieces apart - sides, corners and all, but the link is still not clickable.

Here's my page: 
http://4amnew.4thavenuemedia.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

adjust your css:

```
#twitter
{
   z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: and if possible then instead of slicing the TV in parts use it one single image in background, will save you from lot of hassles.

Answer (score 0):

Give Z-index:250 for #logo id

```
#logo {
height:136px;
left:90px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:240px;
z-index:200;
}
```

IF you want to test link also clickable means give z-index:210; for #twitter